# sequence of calling activate method of components in OSGI bundle

Tags: osgi, aem

In OSGI bundle we can have a lot of components having Activate method.What will be sequence in which they will be called after the bundle is activated?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Components will be activated once all their mandatory references are present. If more than one component can be activated at a certain time then you have no guarantee for the sequence.

Comment: Furthermore, for delayed components, activate will be called only when someone actually requests the component instance.

Answer (score 2):

If the bundles have different Start Levels then all the activation methods of bundles in lower start levels will be executed before the activation methods of bundles on higher start level.

With this logic, you can control the activation method sequence or you can determine what happened based on the logs.

In practice, your bundles must be ordered by dependencies rather than start levels.

Comment: Hi.Thanks for your answer but my question is about activate methods inside components in a single bundle?

Comment: AFAIK, the framework queries for methods in classes with @Activate attribute using standard Java reflection API. You can define service dependencies but in the absence of this, most of the classes and their activator methods will be enumerated in unsorted/unordered manner as none of the reflection API's follow any sorting order. As such, the answer to your question, is that the order of call to activation method is undefined.

Answer (score 1):

As Christian said this is *not defined*.  Once dependencies are satisfied OSGI will activate that service.

As a second point - your services should not depend on a startup sequence.  If they do that's bad practice.  Why is this relevant to your project? Perhaps we can help you architect it.

Answer (score 1):

As others have pointed out, this is not defined.

That said, sometimes there are good reasons to call several methods in given order during activation. If that is your case, you could always have a single "Activate" method that calls all the others. This way you can apply whatever order logic fits best for your usecase. It could even take into account configuration values if needed.